# Box2D GetReactionForce functionality

Tags: c++, box2d

I am looking into the Box2D Code at b2DistanceJoint.cpp onto the function GetReactionForce(float32 inv_dt).
I need to know how the code in it works

```
b2Vec2 b2DistanceJoint::GetReactionForce(float32 inv_dt) const
{
b2Vec2 F = (inv_dt * m_impulse) * m_u;
return F;
}
```

Where do those variables m_impulse and m_u come from?
Are they predefined somewhere and what specifies their value?

Thanks for incoming answers :)

Comment: This is C++ *only*, and not C (Box2D is a C++ library, the actual source line is `b2Vec2 b2DistanceJoint::GetReactionForce(float32 inv_dt) const` *AND* the answer depends on specifics of C++ class declarations). Please use the tags appropriately.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I added C, and that I forgot about the vector, do you maybe still know the answer to this? :(

Comment: It has nothing to do with the vector, it has to do with the fact that `m_impulse` and `m_u` are class member variables, and that there's an implicit `this->` dereference in the code. And it all depends on `GetReactionForce` being a method, so you removing the `b2DistanceJoint::` portion changes the answer completely (in fact, there *is* no answer as it is). At any rate, see the corresponding header file.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for that, I changed it.
Anyway in the function
     void b2DistanceJoint::InitVelocityConstraints(const b2SolverData&    data)
it  is declared what m_u is and m_impulse is edited, but is this changement of the variables global? Apart from that the variable m_impulse is declared in
    b2DistanceJoint::b2DistanceJoint(const b2DistanceJointDef* def)
    : b2Joint(def)
to be 0, so it has to be changed somewhere, because else all is multiplied by 0?

Answer (score 0):

The header file give you that both variables are protected member of the class.

How they are used and initialized depends of how you initialized and used your b2DistanceJoint instance.

As far as I can see m_impulse depends of your object (it is copied in the copy constructor) while m_u is a temporary variable used in other methods.

You may wanna use a debugger to know the exact values they contains.

Comment: So to change those variables I will need to call     
    void b2DistanceJoint::InitVelocityConstraints(const b2SolverData& data) right? But I never call it in my program... It still calculates everything right. Does this function get called somewhere else because else m_impulse would stay 0.0f and the result would always be 0.

Comment: I really can't help you with these few info, if you had a few line explaining why you want to know how it work or in which context you use it it would be helpfull. Else try to look at the execution flow with a debuger or a recursive call graph from an IDE.

Comment: I am trying this program: https://github.com/noshbar/BridgeBuilder
The code is pretty simple.
The essential part is in physics.h in the function addSupport, where the b2DistanceJointDef is initialized and the function HandleSupportForce where getReactionForce is called. Anyway I don't see where m_u or m_impulse (from the function getReactionForce of b2DistanceJoint) are declared or changed. Please help! :(